# Optimize update SQLite subquery or at least break into chunks

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

The following query ran 24h before I killed it.  It resulted in a journal file as big as the database itself (25GB journal file, 27GB database file), and took a few hours to revert after the kill:

```
ALTER TABLE core ADD COLUMN pointcount;
UPDATE core SET pointcount = (SELECT pointcount FROM pointcountsByZip WHERE zip = core.zip);
```

**The database**

- `core` is about 13 million rows.
- `pointcountsByZip` is about a thousand rows.

**Intended use**

- Data analysis for a single user
- I always need to pull out the fully merged form (e.g. I need a version of `core` where the pointcount column is repeated over and over again for each id in `core`)
- Fairly infrequent updates (but they can't take a day per column!)

**About the update**

- I realize by doing this I'm de-normalizing the database.

**Possibilities I see for optimization**

1. Keep the database normalized, then do a left outer join each time I read it.
2. Denormalize the database in one big operation as above
3. Break the denormalizing (funny how close that is to "demoralizing") update into chunks--by ZIP or whatnot.

I'm looking for the `SELECT * FROM core` to be as fast as possible, subject to the `UPDATE` not taking multiple days.  It would be nice if the `UPDATE` also gave me some indication of its status (e.g. if I ran 100 updates on 1/100th of the database, I would know approximately how far along it was, for instance, as well as be able to abort without losing all the changes).  Disk space is not really a consideration, although it's always nice.

** Edit: The execution plan**

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN UPDATE core SET zip_pointcountUC = (SELECT zip_pointcountUC FROM clinicCountsByzip WHERE zip = core.zip);
0|Trace|0|0|0||00|
1|Goto|0|536|0||00|
2|Null|0|1|2||00|
3|OpenRead|0|255|0|494|00|
4|Rewind|0|8|0||00|
5|Rowid|0|2|0||00|
6|RowSetAdd|1|2|0||00|
7|Next|0|5|0||01|
8|Close|0|0|0||00|
9|OpenWrite|0|255|0|494|00|
10|RowSetRead|1|534|2||00|
11|NotExists|0|10|2||00|
12|Null|0|3|496||00|
13|Column|0|0|3||00|
14|Column|0|1|4||00|
15|Column|0|2|5||00|
16|Column|0|3|6||00|
17|Column|0|4|7||00|
18|Column|0|5|8||00|
19|Column|0|6|9||00|
20|Column|0|7|10||00|
21|Column|0|8|11||00|
22|Column|0|9|12||00|
23|Column|0|10|13||00|
24|Column|0|11|14||00|
25|Column|0|12|15||00|
26|Column|0|13|16||00|
27|Column|0|14|17||00|
28|Column|0|15|18||00|
29|Column|0|16|19||00|
30|Column|0|17|20||00|
31|Column|0|18|21||00|
32|Column|0|19|22||00|
33|Column|0|20|23||00|
34|Column|0|21|24||00|
35|Column|0|22|25||00|
36|Column|0|23|26||00|
37|Column|0|24|27||00|
38|Column|0|25|28||00|
39|Column|0|26|29||00|
40|Column|0|27|30||00|
41|Column|0|28|31||00|
42|Column|0|29|32||00|
43|Column|0|30|33||00|
44|Column|0|31|34||00|
45|Column|0|32|35||00|
46|Column|0|33|36||00|
47|Column|0|34|37||00|
48|Column|0|35|38||00|
49|Column|0|36|39||00|
50|Column|0|37|40||00|
51|Column|0|38|41||00|
52|Column|0|39|42||00|
53|Column|0|40|43||00|
54|Column|0|41|44||00|
55|Column|0|42|45||00|
56|Column|0|43|46||00|
57|Column|0|44|47||00|
58|Column|0|45|48||00|
59|Column|0|46|49||00|
60|Column|0|47|50||00|
61|Column|0|48|51||00|
62|Column|0|49|52||00|
63|Column|0|50|53||00|
64|Column|0|51|54||00|
65|Column|0|52|55||00|
66|Column|0|53|56||00|
67|Column|0|54|57||00|
68|Column|0|55|58||00|
69|Column|0|56|59||00|
70|Column|0|57|60||00|
71|Column|0|58|61||00|
72|Column|0|59|62||00|
73|Column|0|60|63||00|
74|Column|0|61|64||00|
75|Column|0|62|65||00|
76|Column|0|63|66||00|
77|Column|0|64|67||00|
78|Column|0|65|68||00|
79|Column|0|66|69||00|
80|Column|0|67|70||00|
81|Column|0|68|71||00|
82|Column|0|69|72||00|
83|Column|0|70|73||00|
84|Column|0|71|74||00|
85|Column|0|72|75||00|
86|Column|0|73|76||00|
87|Column|0|74|77||00|
88|Column|0|75|78||00|
89|Column|0|76|79||00|
90|Column|0|77|80||00|
91|Column|0|78|81||00|
92|Column|0|79|82||00|
93|Column|0|80|83||00|
94|Column|0|81|84||00|
95|Column|0|82|85||00|
96|Column|0|83|86||00|
97|Column|0|84|87||00|
98|Column|0|85|88||00|
99|Column|0|86|89||00|
100|Column|0|87|90||00|
101|Column|0|88|91||00|
102|Column|0|89|92||00|
103|Column|0|90|93||00|
104|Column|0|91|94||00|
105|Column|0|92|95||00|
106|Column|0|93|96||00|
107|Column|0|94|97||00|
108|Column|0|95|98||00|
109|Column|0|96|99||00|
110|Column|0|97|100||00|
111|Column|0|98|101||00|
112|Column|0|99|102||00|
113|Column|0|100|103||00|
114|Column|0|101|104||00|
115|Column|0|102|105||00|
116|Column|0|103|106||00|
117|Column|0|104|107||00|
118|Column|0|105|108||00|
119|Column|0|106|109||00|
120|Column|0|107|110||00|
121|Column|0|108|111||00|
122|Column|0|109|112||00|
123|Column|0|110|113||00|
124|Column|0|111|114||00|
125|Column|0|112|115||00|
126|Column|0|113|116||00|
127|Column|0|114|117||00|
128|Column|0|115|118||00|
129|Column|0|116|119||00|
130|Column|0|117|120||00|
131|Column|0|118|121||00|
132|Column|0|119|122||00|
133|Column|0|120|123||00|
134|Column|0|121|124||00|
135|Column|0|122|125||00|
136|Column|0|123|126||00|
137|Column|0|124|127||00|
138|Column|0|125|128||00|
139|Column|0|126|129||00|
140|Column|0|127|130||00|
141|Column|0|128|131||00|
142|Column|0|129|132||00|
143|Column|0|130|133||00|
144|Column|0|131|134||00|
145|Column|0|132|135||00|
146|Column|0|133|136||00|
147|Column|0|134|137||00|
148|Column|0|135|138||00|
149|Column|0|136|139||00|
150|Column|0|137|140||00|
151|Column|0|138|141||00|
152|RealAffinity|141|0|0||00|
153|Column|0|139|142||00|
154|Column|0|140|143||00|
155|Column|0|141|144||00|
156|Column|0|142|145||00|
157|Column|0|143|146||00|
158|Column|0|144|147||00|
159|Column|0|145|148||00|
160|Column|0|146|149||00|
161|Column|0|147|150||00|
162|Column|0|148|151||00|
163|Column|0|149|152||00|
164|Column|0|150|153||00|
165|Column|0|151|154||00|
166|Column|0|152|155||00|
167|Column|0|153|156||00|
168|Column|0|154|157||00|
169|Column|0|155|158||00|
170|Column|0|156|159||00|
171|Column|0|157|160||00|
172|Column|0|158|161||00|
173|Column|0|159|162||00|
174|Column|0|160|163||00|
175|Column|0|161|164||00|
176|Column|0|162|165||00|
177|Column|0|163|166||00|
178|Column|0|164|167||00|
179|Column|0|165|168||00|
180|Column|0|166|169||00|
181|Column|0|167|170||00|
182|Column|0|168|171||00|
183|Column|0|169|172||00|
184|Column|0|170|173||00|
185|Column|0|171|174||00|
186|Column|0|172|175||00|
187|Column|0|173|176||00|
188|Column|0|174|177||00|
189|Column|0|175|178||00|
190|Column|0|176|179||00|
191|Column|0|177|180||00|
192|Column|0|178|181||00|
193|Column|0|179|182||00|
194|Column|0|180|183||00|
195|Column|0|181|184||00|
196|Column|0|182|185||00|
197|Column|0|183|186||00|
198|Column|0|184|187||00|
199|Column|0|185|188||00|
200|Column|0|186|189||00|
201|Column|0|187|190||00|
202|Column|0|188|191||00|
203|Column|0|189|192||00|
204|Column|0|190|193||00|
205|Column|0|191|194||00|
206|Column|0|192|195||00|
207|Column|0|193|196||00|
208|Column|0|194|197||00|
209|Column|0|195|198||00|
210|Column|0|196|199||00|
211|Column|0|197|200||00|
212|Column|0|198|201||00|
213|Column|0|199|202||00|
214|Column|0|200|203||00|
215|Column|0|201|204||00|
216|Column|0|202|205||00|
217|Column|0|203|206||00|
218|Column|0|204|207||00|
219|Column|0|205|208||00|
220|Column|0|206|209||00|
221|Column|0|207|210||00|
222|Column|0|208|211||00|
223|Column|0|209|212||00|
224|Column|0|210|213||00|
225|Column|0|211|214||00|
226|Column|0|212|215||00|
227|Column|0|213|216||00|
228|Column|0|214|217||00|
229|Column|0|215|218||00|
230|Column|0|216|219||00|
231|Column|0|217|220||00|
232|Column|0|218|221||00|
233|Column|0|219|222||00|
234|Column|0|220|223||00|
235|Column|0|221|224||00|
236|Column|0|222|225||00|
237|Column|0|223|226||00|
238|Column|0|224|227||00|
239|Column|0|225|228||00|
240|Column|0|226|229||00|
241|Column|0|227|230||00|
242|Column|0|228|231||00|
243|Column|0|229|232||00|
244|Column|0|230|233||00|
245|Column|0|231|234||00|
246|Column|0|232|235||00|
247|Column|0|233|236||00|
248|Column|0|234|237||00|
249|Column|0|235|238||00|
250|Column|0|236|239||00|
251|Column|0|237|240||00|
252|Column|0|238|241||00|
253|Column|0|239|242||00|
254|Column|0|240|243||00|
255|Column|0|241|244||00|
256|Column|0|242|245||00|
257|Column|0|243|246||00|
258|Column|0|244|247||00|
259|Column|0|245|248||00|
260|Column|0|246|249||00|
261|Column|0|247|250||00|
262|Column|0|248|251||00|
263|Column|0|249|252||00|
264|Column|0|250|253||00|
265|Column|0|251|254||00|
266|Column|0|252|255||00|
267|Column|0|253|256||00|
268|Column|0|254|257||00|
269|Column|0|255|258||00|
270|Column|0|256|259||00|
271|Column|0|257|260||00|
272|Column|0|258|261||00|
273|Column|0|259|262||00|
274|Column|0|260|263||00|
275|Column|0|261|264||00|
276|Column|0|262|265||00|
277|Column|0|263|266||00|
278|Column|0|264|267||00|
279|Column|0|265|268||00|
280|Column|0|266|269||00|
281|Column|0|267|270||00|
282|Column|0|268|271||00|
283|Column|0|269|272||00|
284|Column|0|270|273||00|
285|Column|0|271|274||00|
286|Column|0|272|275||00|
287|Column|0|273|276||00|
288|Column|0|274|277||00|
289|RealAffinity|277|0|0||00|
290|Column|0|275|278||00|
291|Column|0|276|279||00|
292|Column|0|277|280||00|
293|Column|0|278|281||00|
294|Column|0|279|282||00|
295|Column|0|280|283||00|
296|Column|0|281|284||00|
297|Column|0|282|285||00|
298|Column|0|283|286||00|
299|Column|0|284|287||00|
300|Column|0|285|288||00|
301|Column|0|286|289||00|
302|Column|0|287|290||00|
303|Column|0|288|291||00|
304|Column|0|289|292||00|
305|Column|0|290|293||00|
306|Column|0|291|294||00|
307|Column|0|292|295||00|
308|Column|0|293|296||00|
309|Column|0|294|297||00|
310|Column|0|295|298||00|
311|Column|0|296|299||00|
312|Column|0|297|300||00|
313|Column|0|298|301||00|
314|Column|0|299|302||00|
315|Column|0|300|303||00|
316|Column|0|301|304||00|
317|Column|0|302|305||00|
318|Column|0|303|306||00|
319|Column|0|304|307||00|
320|Column|0|305|308||00|
321|Column|0|306|309||00|
322|Column|0|307|310||00|
323|Column|0|308|311||00|
324|Column|0|309|312||00|
325|Column|0|310|313||00|
326|Column|0|311|314||00|
327|Column|0|312|315||00|
328|Column|0|313|316||00|
329|Column|0|314|317||00|
330|Column|0|315|318||00|
331|Column|0|316|319||00|
332|Column|0|317|320||00|
333|Column|0|318|321||00|
334|Column|0|319|322||00|
335|Column|0|320|323||00|
336|Column|0|321|324||00|
337|Column|0|322|325||00|
338|Column|0|323|326||00|
339|Column|0|324|327||00|
340|Column|0|325|328||00|
341|Column|0|326|329||00|
342|Column|0|327|330||00|
343|Column|0|328|331||00|
344|Column|0|329|332||00|
345|Column|0|330|333||00|
346|Column|0|331|334||00|
347|Column|0|332|335||00|
348|Column|0|333|336||00|
349|Column|0|334|337||00|
350|Column|0|335|338||00|
351|Column|0|336|339||00|
352|Column|0|337|340||00|
353|Column|0|338|341||00|
354|Column|0|339|342||00|
355|Column|0|340|343||00|
356|Column|0|341|344||00|
357|Column|0|342|345||00|
358|Column|0|343|346||00|
359|Column|0|344|347||00|
360|Column|0|345|348||00|
361|Column|0|346|349||00|
362|Column|0|347|350||00|
363|RealAffinity|350|0|0||00|
364|Column|0|348|351||00|
365|Column|0|349|352||00|
366|Column|0|350|353||00|
367|Column|0|351|354||00|
368|Column|0|352|355||00|
369|Column|0|353|356||00|
370|Column|0|354|357||00|
371|Column|0|355|358||00|
372|Column|0|356|359||00|
373|Column|0|357|360||00|
374|Column|0|358|361||00|
375|Column|0|359|362||00|
376|Column|0|360|363||00|
377|Column|0|361|364||00|
378|Column|0|362|365||00|
379|Column|0|363|366||00|
380|Column|0|364|367||00|
381|Column|0|365|368||00|
382|Column|0|366|369||00|
383|Column|0|367|370||00|
384|Column|0|368|371||00|
385|Column|0|369|372||00|
386|Column|0|370|373||00|
387|Column|0|371|374||00|
388|Column|0|372|375||00|
389|Column|0|373|376||00|
390|Column|0|374|377||00|
391|Column|0|375|378||00|
392|Column|0|376|379||00|
393|Column|0|377|380||00|
394|Column|0|378|381||00|
395|Column|0|379|382||00|
396|Column|0|380|383||00|
397|Column|0|381|384||00|
398|Column|0|382|385||00|
399|Column|0|383|386||00|
400|Column|0|384|387||00|
401|Column|0|385|388||00|
402|Column|0|386|389||00|
403|Column|0|387|390||00|
404|Column|0|388|391||00|
405|Column|0|389|392||00|
406|Column|0|390|393||00|
407|Column|0|391|394||00|
408|Column|0|392|395||00|
409|Column|0|393|396||00|
410|Column|0|394|397||00|
411|Column|0|395|398||00|
412|RealAffinity|398|0|0||00|
413|Column|0|396|399||00|
414|Column|0|397|400||00|
415|Column|0|398|401||00|
416|Column|0|399|402||00|
417|Column|0|400|403||00|
418|RealAffinity|403|0|0||00|
419|Column|0|401|404||00|
420|RealAffinity|404|0|0||00|
421|Column|0|402|405||00|
422|Column|0|403|406||00|
423|Column|0|404|407||00|
424|RealAffinity|407|0|0||00|
425|Column|0|405|408||00|
426|RealAffinity|408|0|0||00|
427|Column|0|406|409||00|
428|Column|0|407|410||00|
429|RealAffinity|410|0|0||00|
430|Column|0|408|411||00|
431|RealAffinity|411|0|0||00|
432|Column|0|409|412||00|
433|RealAffinity|412|0|0||00|
434|Column|0|410|413|NULL|00|
435|Column|0|411|414|NULL|00|
436|Column|0|412|415|NULL|00|
437|Column|0|413|416|NULL|00|
438|Column|0|414|417|NULL|00|
439|Column|0|415|418|NULL|00|
440|Column|0|416|419|NULL|00|
441|Column|0|417|420|NULL|00|
442|Column|0|418|421|NULL|00|
443|Column|0|419|422|NULL|00|
444|Column|0|420|423|NULL|00|
445|Column|0|421|424|NULL|00|
446|Column|0|422|425|NULL|00|
447|Column|0|423|426|NULL|00|
448|Column|0|424|427|NULL|00|
449|Column|0|425|428|NULL|00|
450|Column|0|426|429|NULL|00|
451|Column|0|427|430|NULL|00|
452|Column|0|428|431|NULL|00|
453|Column|0|429|432|NULL|00|
454|Column|0|430|433|NULL|00|
455|Column|0|431|434|NULL|00|
456|Column|0|432|435|NULL|00|
457|Column|0|433|436|NULL|00|
458|Column|0|434|437|NULL|00|
459|Column|0|435|438|NULL|00|
460|Column|0|436|439|NULL|00|
461|Column|0|437|440|NULL|00|
462|Column|0|438|441|NULL|00|
463|Column|0|439|442|NULL|00|
464|Column|0|440|443|NULL|00|
465|Column|0|441|444|NULL|00|
466|Column|0|442|445|NULL|00|
467|Column|0|443|446|NULL|00|
468|Column|0|444|447|NULL|00|
469|Column|0|445|448|NULL|00|
470|Column|0|446|449|NULL|00|
471|Column|0|447|450|NULL|00|
472|Column|0|448|451|NULL|00|
473|Column|0|449|452|NULL|00|
474|Column|0|450|453|NULL|00|
475|Column|0|451|454|NULL|00|
476|Column|0|452|455|NULL|00|
477|Column|0|453|456|NULL|00|
478|Column|0|454|457|NULL|00|
479|Column|0|455|458|NULL|00|
480|Column|0|456|459|NULL|00|
481|Column|0|457|460|NULL|00|
482|Column|0|458|461|NULL|00|
483|Column|0|459|462|NULL|00|
484|Column|0|460|463|NULL|00|
485|Column|0|461|464|NULL|00|
486|Column|0|462|465|NULL|00|
487|Column|0|463|466|NULL|00|
488|Column|0|464|467|NULL|00|
489|Column|0|465|468|NULL|00|
490|Column|0|466|469|NULL|00|
491|Column|0|467|470|NULL|00|
492|Column|0|468|471|NULL|00|
493|Column|0|469|472|NULL|00|
494|Column|0|470|473|NULL|00|
495|Column|0|471|474|NULL|00|
496|Column|0|472|475|NULL|00|
497|Column|0|473|476|NULL|00|
498|Column|0|474|477|NULL|00|
499|Column|0|475|478|NULL|00|
500|Column|0|476|479|NULL|00|
501|Column|0|477|480|NULL|00|
502|Column|0|478|481|NULL|00|
503|Column|0|479|482|NULL|00|
504|Column|0|480|483|NULL|00|
505|Column|0|481|484|NULL|00|
506|Column|0|482|485|NULL|00|
507|Column|0|483|486|NULL|00|
508|Column|0|484|487|NULL|00|
509|Column|0|485|488|NULL|00|
510|Column|0|486|489|NULL|00|
511|Column|0|487|490|NULL|00|
512|Column|0|488|491|NULL|00|
513|Column|0|489|492||00|
514|Column|0|490|493||00|
515|Column|0|491|494||00|
516|Null|0|497|0||00|
517|Integer|1|498|0||00|
518|OpenRead|3|3609199|0|1|00|
519|Rewind|3|527|0||00|
520|Column|3|0|499||00|
521|Column|0|352|500||00|
522|Ne|500|526|499|collseq(BINARY)|6a|
523|Column|0|492|501||00|
524|Move|501|497|0||00|
525|IfZero|498|527|-1||00|
526|Next|3|520|0||01|
527|Close|3|0|0||00|
528|SCopy|497|495|0||00|
529|Column|0|493|496||00|
530|NotExists|0|531|2||00|
531|MakeRecord|3|494|500|ddddaddadddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddaaaaaaaddddddddaaddaddddddddddddddddddddddddeddddaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaddaaadddddddedaddaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddadedaddeeddeeaeeebbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|00|
532|Insert|0|500|2|core|05|
533|Goto|0|10|0||00|
534|Close|0|0|0||00|
535|Halt|0|0|0||00|
536|Transaction|0|1|0||00|
537|VerifyCookie|0|171|0||00|
538|TableLock|0|255|1|core|00|
539|TableLock|0|3609199|0|clinicCountsByzip|00|
540|Goto|0|2|0||00|
```

Comment: The only reason i can think of right away for this taking so long, is the absence of an index on pointcountsByZip.Zip - is it there?
Can you show the execution plan for this query? Because 13 million updates with an (indexed) lookup from a mere 1000 rows should be fairly fast.
And now I see it's sqlite. Stupid question, but is SQLite meant for 27GB databases?

Comment: @oerkelens Added the execution plan.  I don't have an index on either zip, and clearly I should.  So that's the first step.  My (erroneous?) assumption was that since I was only planning on doing this merge once that building the index would take longer, but perhaps I was very, very wrong....

Comment: An index on that 1000 rows will cost you nothing compared to 13 million full table scans when you do this update :)
Of course i mean an index on pointcountsByZip, not your new column. That _would_ take extra time with every update :)

Comment: There's no index on core.zip either currently.

Comment: Good, i would suggest not putting one there :)

Comment: Haha good to know :-).  So index on pointcountsByZip.zip, but not on core.zip.  Re: SQLite question, I've seen plenty of posts claiming it scales nicely to much hugerier databases, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you use a simple query like your example that you killed after 24 hours, you'll never get any feedback on how close, or how far, it is to finishing.

I've had some experience with something similar to this, but with much fewer records (in the 30,000ish range), and in a table with over 150 columns (a lot I know).

When I tried what you're basically doing, I waited forever, and then finally got an out of memory exception. My problem is that I was loading like 30,000+ Update commands into a single transaction to try to speed up the updating, which ate up too much memory.

Nowadays in your situation I use two loops. The first loop grabs all the data you need for the Update query from the table (the primary key, and anything else you need to set the value of the column(s) you're modifying).

Before starting the second loop I declare an integer that's equal to 0, and say "Begin Transaction". Each time I run through the loop I add 1 to that integer. Whenever the integer hits say 1,000, I commit the transaction (and free up the memory it was eating by now) and start a brand new one, as well as set the integer back to 0. When I finally exit the second loop I commit the last transaction.

I'm sure you could do much the same thing to update your 13 million rows. You could even make the code only update a half a million or so records at a time, and do that many each day if the whole database is going to take 24+ hours to update that many records.

Comment: I guess I should admit that `core` has about 550 columns, which is how a 13mm row database gets to 27GB.  So "normalized" is a relative term.  Is that my problem?

Comment: Oh, that's probably part of your problem in terms of memory usage slowing things down. I'm not certain how much an extra 500+ columns slow down a Select or Update query if you don't touch them, but I've found that surprisingly, at least in SQLite, after a certain point it's actually faster to grab all the columns in a table in a SQL Select query rather than just 30, at least with a 150ish column table.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a memory problem.  It was maxing out HDD reads for a few hours, then dropped way down on IO and maxing out processor.  Never got close to memory limits at any point (10-15% of 16GB).

Comment: Let me reword that. You have 500+ columns you aren't using in these queries and 13 million records to run through. Even though you aren't touching those columns in these queries, it's possible that all that extra unused data might be slowing down your queries. Think of it this way, if you had an excel file with 100 rows & 20 columns that's 2,000 cells, easy to read in. But if your excel file had 65,000 rows and 256 columns it would be using over 16 million cells, even if only 2,000 had nonblank values. That greatly boosts the size of the table you have to sort though, even if 99% of it's blank

Comment: Hm, that is counter to my (limited) intuition.  Maybe I should read chunks in to R, calculate the mean, then write them back out and merge on the key?  Just seems like this should be faster to keep in DB and it's not.  The other option is to fully regularize the table, which would be efficient but take a lot of work.  And probably only get me down to 300ish columns.